# Ionic Protractor testing, making get requests

Tags: ionic-framework, protractor

I am testing a login page that sends the credentials to an api, and returns either "error" if failed or "user@email.com" on success. If the response is successful, i want it to redirect to another page. So far, this is all I wrote, can someone help me fix this? because now it displays the result of the request.

describe('clicking on the login button', function()
{
    var username, password, loginbutton

```
beforeEach(function(){
    browser.get('#/loginPage');
    username= element(by.id('username'));
    password= element(by.id('password'));
    loginButton= element(by.id('loginButton'));
}); 

it('should validate the credentials for a successful login and display the recommended view', function() {

    // 
    username.sendKeys('user@gmail.com');
    password.sendKeys('abc12345');

    loginButton.click().then(function() 
    {
        browser.get('http://website.com/api/login?email=user@gmail.com&password=abc12345')
         expect(browser.driver.getCurrentUrl()).toMatch('/menu.recommendedJobs')

    },10000)
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use "http" module available in nodeJs to make http request and then process the response recieved from the api call. Look at the below example

```
var http = require('http');

var options = {
   host: 'example.com',
   port: 80,
   path: '/foo.html'
};

http.get(options, function(resp){
   resp.on('data', function(chunk){
   //do something with chunk
  });
}).on("error", function(e){
   console.log("Got error: " + e.message);
});
```